# how to perfectly straighten an object?

Tags: modeling

### **BEFORE**

[image]

### AFTER

[image]

---

Degree is not known.
Is there a method to straighten an object?
no need to re-create.

Comment: @JohnEason 
in the first image, the object is rotated approximately 30 degrees along the x-axis. But it is not known how much exactly.

Comment: Ok. I deleted my comment because I saw what you meant before you added your comment. See if [this YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUYHixJfYQs) video helps.

Comment: Incidentally that video is for Blender 2.8 but I assume you can still do the same in 2.79?

Comment: @JohnEason thank you very much, when I clicked on the link, youtube suggested another video, this video also helped [another-video-yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-q4H81OAjM)

Comment: if there are other ways, i would love to know

Comment: Glad to be able to help. It's not something I've encountered myself but a quick Google search usually finds an answer. You just have to work out how to word your search term to get the answer you need! :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 2.81+

1. In Edit mode select one of the rectangular faces and make a new custom orientation from the orientation menu in top of 3D view:

[image]

2. In Object mode choose affect only origins in the right top corner of the 3D view:

[image]

3. Now in menu **Object** ⇾ **Transform** ⇾ **Align to transform orientation**
4. Disable affect only origins back and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. Object will be perfectly aligned.

### Note for older versions.

In case if you are using older versions, and you haven't affect only origins option which was introduced in 2.81, you can do the following:

1. As before
2. Add new empty object and in menu **Object** ⇾ **Transform** ⇾ **Align to transform orientation**
3. Parent object to empty, select empty and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
4. Select Object and unparent it <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> - Keep transform.
5. Apply transform <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> Rotation

Comment: Thank you! Also remove the custom orientation in step 4